# Download Management

Tags: storage, pdf

Hi I'm not sure if this question already exists but I couldn't find anything on it.

I need to find out if there is anyway of automatically deleting downloads either within a certain time frame ( say they had been in the storage for a month) or once downloads have reached a certain limit (say 30 downloads) it would delete them from storage.

The issue we have is that we provide the tablets for the guys that work on site or in the field who will need to view maps (pdf) and need some automated storage management for the downloads so we wouldnt have to a) manually keep deleting them to save storage or b) giving them a tutorial on how to do this.

Also (but not as importantly) is there a way of view the pdfs (from office 365 sharepoint (sites)) of viewing the pdfs with out downloading them?

The roll out is pretty soon so any help is most appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: As for the automated cleanup, take a look at our [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) and [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) tag wikis. With some automation apps (I'm sure for *Tasker* here, but its a paid app) you could define an event to e.g. check the download directory once a day and delete all files older than X (or all but the newest Y files).